# What is .gksu.lock file

Tags: files, gksu

I have been trying to find out what exactly `/home/user/.gksu.lock` is.

1. What does the file do?
2. If I remove or edit the file, will it affect my system in any way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does the file do?

This is a lock file for gksu (Gtk+ frontend to su(do)). It does nothing if it is on the system (tested it with several gksu nautilus commands; when closing nautilus it did show a "critical" alert ... so it might be a bug that the file is there; EDIT: bug report found for 14.10 but is also has 14.04 in comments: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+bug/1325251 )

> If I remove or edited the file,does it affect my system in any way?

1. Removing: the system will recreate the file when needed so here the answer is: no. If it is gone and someone is using a gksu action somewhere it will fail to finish the task.
2. Editing? The file is empty and probably should be empty. If you edit something in I would expect nothing to happen. Sane answer: no, does nothing. I assume the content is not checked but just the presence of the file should be enough to trigger a notice regarding a lock active.

Comment: are you sure? It seems logical, but mine never disappears after creation.

Comment: Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+bug/1325251 Ubuntu with kernel 3.15.0-2 has a fix.